# Is there a wx Widget to show ANSI escape code colored text?

Tags: text, colors, wxpython, wxwidgets, ansi-escape

I can't seem to find a control that will display text colored with ANSI escape codes.  For example:

```
"\e[0;32mHello \e[0;37mWorld"
```

Would display a green "Hello" and a white "World".

Does one exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that such a widget exists. You may look for some way of changing ANSI codes into HTML and then displaying it in wxWidgets. This may be useful:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577349-convert-a-transcript-with-ansi-escape-sequences-to/

Comment: This works pretty well.  I had to change the code somewhat to eliminate the css in the HTML, since the wxHtmlWindow doesn't support it.  Thanks for the suggestion.